# Is it possible to change style of doughnut chart tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

Currently I have this doughnut chart

[image]

I am trying to change tooltip style like this

[image]

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
   var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
         labels: ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"],
         datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: ['yellow', 'pink', 'red', '#E8A3D7', '#CFA3FD'],
            data: [7, 3, 3, 4, 8],
         }]
      },
      options: {
         legend: {
            position: 'right',
            labels: {
               boxWidth: 12
            }
         }
      }
   });
```

But I couldn't find a way.Does anybody know if this is possible?

https://jsfiddle.net/xm80qzoo/2/